# How to investigate intermittent Postgres connection errors?

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, google-cloud-sql, django

Our webserver (Django-app on Gunicorn running on Google Cloud Run) connects to a Postgres 15 database (on Google Cloud SQL) through Psycopg. Most queries are successful, but recently ~1% of the queries fail on random moments, with random error messages like:

- `connection failed: region:db_name/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly - This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.`
- `got message type "P", length 1380524074`
- `connection failed: region:db_name/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`
- `consuming input failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly - This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.`
- `invalid socket`

Sometimes we see an error at the server side at the same moment, for example:

- `FATAL: canceling authentication due to timeout`
- `FATAL: connection to client lost`
- `FATAL: password authentication failed for user`

The `password authentication failed` error puzzles me: we're always connecting with the same password.

The `got message type "P"` looks cryptic to me, and the length mentioned (over 1G!) is abnormal, I don't see why such a long message is being sent.

In the Django settings file, I tried different settings:

- `CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS` = `True` or `False`
- `CONN_MAX_AGE` = `0` (new connection for every request) or `None` (unlimited persistent connections)

Resources (CPU, memory, disk space, ...) are well below the limits.

We use Unix sockets to connect to the database. Config in Django `settings.py` :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/project:region:instance',
        'NAME': ...,
        'USER': ....,
        'PASSWORD': ...,
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can investigate this problem?

Comment: I would suspect a flaky or mis-configured network.

Comment: Since you're using managed services on both sides, there isn't much you can do apart from trying to work with Google Cloud support to identify the problem.

Comment: I guess that you are using background processes or threads that have connections to Google Cloud SQL. When your container instance is not processing HTTP requests, your container can be CPU rate limited to 0, which means connections will behave bizarrely. As a test, enable `Always on CPU` to see if the problems go away. [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation).

Comment: @JohnHanley Interesting line of thought, I tried enabling "Always on CPU" altough we don't have background processes, we only process HTTP requests. Unfortunately, we still have intermittend connection errors.

Comment: Are you using the Cloud SQL Proxy built-in to Cloud Run or direct IP:PORT for your connections?

Comment: @JohnHanley We use Unix sockets. I just added the Django settings for the database connection in the question above.

Comment: I would open a Google Cloud Issue Tracker [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). I know the Cloud Run team and they are very good at helping solve challenging problems. If you have paid support, go that route as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Google support team found that this was an issue at their side, they will fix the problem shortly.
If you have this issue and can't wait for the fix by Google, you can switch to the [Cloud Run second generation execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments) as a workaround.